# MarkLogic - Tokenize Search Phrase based on XML Field as a dictionary of phrases

Tags: nlp, marklogic

I have a list of "known phrases" stored in an XML Document under an element named **label**. I am trying to figure out how to write a function, that can tokenize a search phrase into all of its **label** pieces (if available).

For instance. I have a Label for North Korea, and ICBM.

If the user types in North Korea ICBM, I would expect to get back two tokens, one for each label as opposed to North and Korea and ICBM.
In another example if the user types in New York City, I would expect only one token (label) of "New York City".

If there is no labels found, it would return the default tokenization of each word.

I tried to start writing this, but am not sure how to do this properly without a while loop facility, and am pretty new to xQuery in general.

The code below was how I started, but quickly realized it would not work for scaling out search terms.
Basically, it checks to see if the full phrase is in the **Label** fields. If it is not, it starts to strip away from the back of the search phrase checking what's left for a label.

```
  let $label-query := cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('','label'), $searchTerm, ('case-insensitive', 'whitespace-sensitive'))

  let $results := cts:search(fn:collection('typea'),$label-query)

  let $test :=
    if (fn:empty($results)) then
        let $tokens := (fn:tokenize($searchTerm, " "))
        let $tokenCount := fn:count($tokens)
            let $lastWord := $tokens[last()]
            let $firstPhrase := $tokens[position() ne (last())]

            let $_ :=
                if (fn:count($firstPhrase)  = 1 ) then
                    ()
                else
                      let $label-query2 := cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('','label'), $firstPhrase, ('case-insensitive', 'whitespace-sensitive'))
                      let $results2 := cts:search(fn:collection('typea'),$label-query2)
                        return
                            if (fn:empty($results2)) then
                                xdmp:log('second empty')
                            else
                                xdmp:log($results2)

        let $l := xdmp:log(  $firstPhrase  )
        return $tokens

    else
        let $_ := xdmp:log('full')
        return element {'result'} {$results}
```

Does anyone have any advice how I could implement this recursively or perhaps any alternate strategies. I am essentially trying to say, break this sentence up into all of the phrases found that exist in the **Label** fields of the **typea** collection. If there are no labels found, tokenize by word.

Thanks I look forward to your guidance.

---

Update to help clarify my ultimate intention.

Below is the document referring to North Korea.

[image]

The goal is to parse the search phrase, and use extra information found in these documents to aid in search.

Meaning if the person types in **DPRK** or **North Korea** they should both search the same way. It should also include **Narrower** Labels as an Or Condition on the search, and will more likely than not be updated to include other relationships that will also be included in search. (IE: Kim Jong Un is Notably Associated with North Korea.)

So in short I would like to reconcile the multi phrase search terms using the **label** field, and then if it was found, use the information from **all labels** + the **narrower labels** as well from that document.

---

Edit 2: Trying to use `cts:highlight` to get the phrases. Once I have the phrases I will do an element lookup to get to the right document, and then get the associated documents data for submission to query building.

The issue now is that the cts:highlight does not always return the full phrase under one `<phrase>` tag.

```
let $phrases :=   cts:highlight(<nod>New York City FC</nod>,      cts:or-query((//label)),      <phrase>{ $cts:text }</phrase>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible alternative approach, if you are using MarkLogic 9, is to set up a custom tokenization dictionary. See custom dictionary API documentation[1](http://docs.marklogic.com/cdict) and search developer's guide[2](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-dictionaries#id_26361) for details.

But the gist is, if you add an entry "North Korea" in your tokenization dictionary for a language, you'll get it back as a single token for that language. This will apply everywhere: in content or searches.

That said, it isn't clear from your code what you are ultimately trying to achieve with this. If it is more accuracy with phrase searches, there are better ways to achieve this (enabling fast-phrase for 2-word phrases, or word positions for longer ones).

If this us about search parsing only, you could still use the tokenization dictionary approach, but you probably want to use a special language code for it so it doesn't mess up your actual content, and then use `cts:tokenize`, e.g. `cts:tokenize("North Korea ICBM","xen")` where `"xen"` is your special language code.

Another approach is to use `cts:highlight` to apply markup to matches to your phrases in the string and go from there:

```
cts:highlight(<node>North Korea ICBM</node>, 
   cts:or-query((//label)), 
   <phrase>{$cts:text}</phrase>)
```

That would embed the markup for any matching phrase: `<node><phrase>North Korea</phrase></node>`

Some care would have to be taken around overlaps, if you want to force a particular winner, by applying the set you want to win first, and then running a second pass with the others.

Comment: Hi @mholstege thanks for your guidance. I updated my question with a little extra color around my ultimate intention. The goal is indeed search parsing, but it also would like to add extra fields from the documents it finds into the search, after it has been parsed

Comment: I am also looking into using a Lexicon on that field to help

Comment: it doesnt look like I can get custom tokenization or lexicon lookups to work properly since phrases will more often than not be compound... I also tried the highlighting strategy, but does not work. In the case of something like "New York City ICBM", each word comes back wrapped in its own `<phrase>` when I would still only expect 2 `phrases`

Comment: I realized why the `cts:highlight` wasnt working properly. I believe it may be to `case sensitivity` . Is there a way to ignore case sensitivity in that highlight context?.... edit: nm, still splitting it up -_-

Comment: Add the appropriate option to your word queries, e.g. "case-sensitive" or "case-insensitive".